# Reflection does not return a correct instance

Tags: java

I have wired experience with reflections. At first some sample code:

```
public abstract class A {

    public A () {
        init();
    }

    public abstract void init ();
}


public class B extends A {

    private int i = 0;

    public B () {
        super();
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public void init () {
        i = 1;
    }
}
```

Somewhere in my code I use the reflection api to instantiate an object B.

```
Class<AbstractSection> bc = (Class<AbstractSection>) Class.forName(B);
Constructor<?> bcon = bc.getConstructor();
B b = (B) bcon.newInstance();
```

What I expected was an instance of B with the variable i set to value '1'. What I got is an instance of B with i still set to '0'.
With a closer look with a debugger I saw that this is not exactly correct: i is NOT still set to '0'. It is changed to '1' in
the init() method and set back to '0' in the very moment when the super() call returns.

Anyone a clue? Thanks in advance,

manuel

PS: I know I can solve this by calling init() not in the super class but in the inheriting constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For starters, this is nothing to do with reflection - you'd get the same results if you instantiate the class yourself.

Your confusion likely stems from the way that the `i` field is defined - it *looks like* it's set to `0` as soon as it "exists".  In reality, the assignment to zero is one of the first lines of your constructor (though, crucially, *after* the call to `super()` as is required by constructors in general).

In other words, your class is exactly equivalent to the following:

```
public class B extends A {

    private int i;

    public B () {
        super();
        i = 0;
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public void init () {
        i = 1;
    }
}
```

I presume you can see now why the output is `0` instead of `1` - because the call to `init()` happens **before** the field is initialised to `0`.

---

It is for this, and other reasons, that on the whole you should avoid calling subclass methods from a superclass constructor - since the subclass won't even have been initialised at this point, so invariants could easily be violated.  (Calling methods on an unconstructed object is always a very bad idea!)  That's the root cause of your problem, and the direction that you should be looking to address with a fix.

Constructors should constrain themselves to only calling methods that are private or final, for this reason.  For more details, see (amongst others):

- [What's wrong with overrideable method calls in constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors)
- [Problem in instance variable initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288601/problem-in-instance-variable-initialization)
- [State of Derived class object when Base class constructor calls overridden method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330390/state-of-derived-class-object-when-base-class-constructor-calls-overridden-method)
- [Don’t call subclass methods from a superclass constructor](http://benpryor.com/blog/2008/01/02/dont-call-subclass-methods-from-a-superclass-constructor/)

Comment: What would be the solution? Would removing` = 0` be enough, or is that implicit anyway?

Comment: @Bart-van-Heukelom: It's implicit anyway for integer fields (though I'm not sure whether `i` would actually be set to zero if the explicit assignment was removed - and I'm not going to look it up because it's irrelevant if you're following the rules).  The solution is **not to call overrideable methods from (parent) constructors**.  So in this case `A`'s constructor should not call `init()`, and instead `B`'s constructor should call it itself.

Comment: @Bart von Heukelom: just to answer your question: it then will be set to '1'.
and Andrzej Doyle: thank you for your answer. very detailed and useful!

Answer (score 1):

Any non-static class properties will be set to their default value in class's constructor:

```
boolean                          false
char                             '\u0000'
byte,short,int,long              0
float, double                    +0.0f or +0.0d
object                           null
```

Answer (score 0):

There will be no difference if you call constructor instead of using reflection.

Declarations like

```
private int i = 0;
```

become part of every declared constructor right after call of super.
So `init` is called before assignment to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the order of execution is as follows: constructor of the subclass calls the superconstructor, that superconstructor sets i = 0, initialization of fields in the subclass then sets i = 1, and finally is executed the rest of the constructor of the subclass.

This follows the general rule: an object is initialized first by a superclass, and then by a subclass. This is why, if you'd try to call a non--static method within super()'s arguments, you'd get an error "cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called". If you'd try to modify a field in super(), you'd get another error message. This prevents initialization of the subclass before the superconstructor initialized it.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers state the  method (generated by the compiler and initializes your fields) is called after super(), so it goes like that:

```
super()
    init() // i = 1
this()
    <init> // i = 0
```

I would like to add that you should not call a method in your constructor which may be overriden by your clients. This may cause unpredictable "fuckup" ;)

More details in effective java, can't find the item rigth now.