# init method in java.util.hashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

while I was going through the source code of `java.util.HashMap` I found declaration of `init`.

Initialization hook for subclasses. This method is called in all constructors and pseudo-constructors (`clone`, `readObject`) after `HashMap` has been initialized but before any entries have been inserted. (In the absence of this method, `readObject` would require explicit knowledge of subclasses.)

```
void init() {
}
```

I found a related question [In Java, is there a legitimate reason to call a non-final method from a class constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477553/in-java-is-there-a-legitimate-reason-to-call-a-non-final-method-from-a-class-co)

But still I am not able to understand what's the purpose of init and why `readObject` require explicit knowledge of subclass? Could any one explain with  an example

Comment: IMHO - A good practice would be to clarify any remaining doubt (if any), or accept the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment says, it's an initialization hook for subclasses. Every subclass can override `init()` appropriately to perform whatever initialization is required in every case, *without* having to provide another implementation of `readObject` for deserialization and reimplement `clone()` themselves.

For example, in `LinkedHashMap`, the `init()` method is overridden to set up the linked list. Think about where that would happen when deserializing if `init()` wasn't available.

Comment: A different view, init() would not be required if the Hashmap was a final class. But as its extendible, we need to care about child class(es) too.